# Como desactivar la selección de elementos por defecto que tienen los navegadores?

Tags: jquery

alguien sabría que hacer para que no me **seleccione** la imagen?

Se podria hacer con jquery o javascript?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Aque te refieres que NO seleccione la imagen? que no le pueda dar click derecho > ver imagen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar a tu imagen la propiedad cursor con el valor not-allowed, esto para que muestre el cursor como una opción que no se puede realizar.

También para el completo funcionamiento de lo que requieres a tu imagen le puedes agregar onmousedown y ondragstart, los cuales son eventos que se ejecutan bajo ciertas interacciones, el primero es cuando presiones un botón del mouse y el segundo evento se ejecuta cuando comienzas a arrastrar ese elemento. En estos dos eventos retornamos false para que no ejecuten nada.

El código completo sería:

```
<img ondragstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;"  src="https://brand.jquery.org/resources/jquery-mark-light.gif" alt="">


img { cursor:not-allowed; }
```

[Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/checosele/y9kdb21r/) te dejo el ejemplo completo.

Answer (score 0):

Con jquery puedes emplear el evento **contextmenu** así:

```js
$("img").on("contextmenu", function(e){
  return false;
});
```

```css
img{
 cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6PgF.png" width="200"/>
```